# Jenkins me muestra que mi proyecto fue SATISFACTORIO cuando yo le lancé un error

Tags: java, jenkins, svn

estoy implementando un proyecto de la universidad con un amigo y yo, estamos Tenemos conectado Jenkins, VisualSVN Server y Eclipse IDE.

Hicimos lo siguiente:
* Colocamos unos trozos de codigo en el metodo que para que la clase estuviera mal y guardamos e hicimos commit al proyecto, al revisar en el jenkins efectivamente se ve que se realizó el cambio de lo que enviamos, pero el Jenkins me sigue mostrando que el proyecto está bien cuando debería estar mal por haber hecho que la clase lanzara error,

Algo me falta configurar?

Adjunto imagen[image: Imagen de Jenkins]

Comment: Te sugiero agregar información de cómo está configurado tu job en jenkins. Sobre todo el build, ya que pareciera que está reportando éxito a pesar de que la compilación debió fallar.

Comment: @JavierReséndiz, los datos que tengo del repositorio son: https://SQABOG-TGP2706/svn/Siebel y tengo esto en programador, eso es desde jenkins
 #Cada 2 minutos
H/2 * * * * o no sé si desde Jenkins donde lo arreglo o en que parte

Comment: Si le das click ahí donde está el icono azul, entras al Job, dentro de la información del Job, puedes entrar a ver la configuración y de ahí ves los pasos que conforman el Job. Uno de esos pasos debe ser el de Build, ese es el que necesitas verificar que esté correctamente configurado.

Comment: @JavierReséndiz no se le puede dar clic en el botón azul, es un boton que solo muestra el estado de la compilación pero y no me deja entrar al job, o no sé si conozcas otra rutam yo entro a configuraciones pero no sé que colocarle